# Context.User.Identity.GetUserName() for 2 website is accesing same user

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created 2 webapplication in Visual Studio 2013 using C#.

I have registered 2 new users in both the applications.

Now if I run both the application in Google Chrome. I am getting the following;-

1) If I login in one website and if I refresh the other website page. It is also logged in.

How can i make it seperate, so that both can have there seperate users?

Has it someting to do with `Context.User.Identity`, are both site using same cookies??

Please help me in understanding it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you haven't explicitly changed the authentication configuration in the `web.config` across both websites, then the behaviour you are seeing is [by design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

> To configure forms authentication across applications, you set attributes of the forms and machineKey sections of the Web.config file to the same values for all applications that are participating in shared forms authentication.
>
> ...Unless otherwise noted, the **name**, **protection**, **path**, **validationKey**, **validation**, **decryptionKey**, and **decryption** attributes must be identical across all applications.

So, if you want an independent ticket for each site, the easiest solution would be to give each site it's own distinct ticket name

```
<forms name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH_SITEA" ... />
<forms name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH_SITEB" ... />
```

For security purposes, you might also want to consider using different encryption/decryption keys as well.

Comment: Hi @James,

    <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms" >
      <forms

            loginUrl="/Account/Login.aspx"
            name ="Website1"
     />
    </authentication>

    <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms" >
      <forms

            loginUrl="/Account/Login.aspx"
            name ="Website2"
     />
    </authentication>

as per you suggestion i added the following but still result is same

Comment: @vikas have you cleared the existing cookies & restarted the websites?

Comment: yes i have done, even i tested it in Firefox also. It is doing same, no change

Comment: Well it appears as though your sites are still pulling in the old `.ASPXAUTH` one, are you testing these locally through VS or from a deployed environment?

Comment: No, It is local, testing from Visual Studio, There are only 2 cookies on the page

Cookie
.AspNet.ApplicationCookie
__AntiXsrfToken

Answer (score 0):

You can make the logins seperate by doing the following (my guess is that you want the sessions seperate as well), which Microsoft advise to do if running multiple websites from a web server, most likely to avoid this cross cookie issue...

In your web.config give the session and the authentication cookies unique names, e.g.

```
<sessionState cookieName="UNIQUESESSION1" timeout="20"/>
```

and

```
<forms timeout="2880" name="UNIQUEAUTH1" />
```